# PgAdmin4 | Permission denied for table testapp_testquestion

Tags: postgresql

El tratar de mostrar el contenido de tablas de una base de datos me devuelve el siguiente error. No comprendo bien el motivo, ya que al acceder a ver las tablas o la arquitectura de la base de datos ya he tenido que introducir usuario y password, en cambio el contenido de la tabla no me deja ver.

**Error:**

Permission denied for table testapp_testquestion

SQL state: 42501

Answer (score 1, accepted):

¿Con qué usuario estás intentando hacer la consulta?

Intenta darle permisos [SELECT](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/sql-grant.html):

```
GRANT SELECT ON `testapp_testquestion` TO `usuario;
```

Comment: Efectivamente Adrián, era un tema de privilegios que no tenía el usuario con el cual había entrado a Pgadmin4. Ahora que entro con usuario postgres con todos los privilegios, puedo ver todo el contenido sin problema. Muchas gracias una vez más Adrián. ; )

Comment: Para eso estamos. Me alegro poder ayudarte.